# Connecting SocketIO In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I'm using the default example provided in the https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc GitHub repo. And SocketIO throws an error that the handshake failed and the server returned with status code 400. I have successfully connected to the server with the socket.io Javascript library.please help Thanks in Advance.

Code..

```
socketIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [socketIO connectToHost: @"localhost" onPort:3000];

- (void) socketIODidConnect:(SocketIO *)socket{
    NSLog(@"socket.io connected.");
}
# pragma mark socket.IO-objc delegate methods
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveEvent()");
}

- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket onError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"onError() %@", error);
}
- (void) socketIODidDisconnect:(SocketIO *)socket disconnectedWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"socket.io disconnected. did error occur? %@", error);
}
```

Error Msg

> 2017-02-23 10:44:50.674 Chat[940:25247] Connecting to socket with URL:
>   http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1487826890674 2017-02-23
>   10:44:50.747 Chat[940:25247] didReceiveResponse() 400 2017-02-23
>   10:44:50.750 Chat[940:25247] ERROR: handshake failed ... Server
>   returned status code 400

Comment: Are you using socket.io version 0.9 or 1.0 for server side ? @Deepak Kumar

Comment: how to check socket.io version and server side version?

Comment: Objective-C version of socket.io is only supporting socket.io 0.9 version . so please check the server side version . From where did you download server side framework ?

Comment: command to check server side version.?

Comment: https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Comment: The current version of this library does not support socket.io v1.0.
So if you want to use socket.io-objc, please fall back to v0.9.x.

Check first two lines there

Comment: solution? when i open socketIO 0.9. show same code

Comment: Use the Swift code : https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift